# Full-page display of a graphic in a figure float environment

Tags: floats

I want to display a graphic as an illustration to a full page text. I do not need a caption.

As sliding environment I use the figure environment. I include the graphic itself using includegraphics. It is a multi-page PDF document. Therefore I also use `page=1`.

The whole thing looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ph]
    \includegraphics[page=1,origin=c, valign=c, width=\pagewidth, height=\pageheight]{illustration.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Furthermore I already went the way of `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`
which produced various error messages.

Is there no solution using Ti*k*Z?

Thanks a lot!

> Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)